# How to update @State variable and pass it on in iOS 14?

Tags: swiftui

in iOS14 the following SwiftUI code does not work the same as in iOS13.x

If you run this on iOS 14 device, the "selection" variable, although being changed and printed correctly in console, does not get passed to the next view presented as .sheet()

It works as expected if you display the "selection" variable in the initial view.

Just uncomment
//            Text("Currently: (selection.rawValue)")

If you run it on iOS13.x device, it works as expected without the need to display the value being updated.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView:View {
    
    @State private var selection=MyView.TestEnum.ONE
    @State private var presentSheet=false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
//            Text("Currently: \(selection.rawValue)")
            Button(action: {
                selection=MyView.TestEnum.TWO
                integer=2
                print("selecting: \(selection.rawValue)")
                presentSheet=true
            }, label: {
                Text("Select TWO")
            })
            .sheet(isPresented: $presentSheet, onDismiss: {
                print("dismissed")
            }) {
                MyView(tenum: selection)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyView:View {
    enum TestEnum: String, Codable {
        case ONE="ONE"
        case TWO="TWO"
    }
    var tenum:TestEnum
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("enum: \(tenum.rawValue)")
        }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```